# Joining two tables and one attribute being linked to multiple values in the other table

Tags: mysql

I've run into a problem. I am trying to create two tables that are interlinked to each other. The first table is the Vendor table that consists of the vendor name, vendor ID, quotations and the partner name whereas the second table is the quotations table that would consist monthly quotations of each vendor such as

**Vendor Table**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Vendor ID | Vendor Name | Partner Name | Quotations
1         | XYZ Company | XYZ Partner  | (click to view quotations)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And when we click on "View Quotations" the data should be shown like
**Quotations** 
Vendor Name: XYZ Company
Vendor ID: 1
Partner Name: XYZ Partner

Quotations Table

```
-----------------------------------------
Quotation No | Month | FILE
1            | Jun   | DOWNLOAD (.PDF)
2            | july  | DOWNLOAD (.PDF)
-----------------------------------------
```

The problem I'm facing here is to figure out whether LEFT OUTER JOIN will be used or not. I mean if I'm trying to link the vendors table to the quotations table so that a vendor can have multiple quotations.

Secondly, I'm confused about how can I input data in both the tables, an ordinary INSERT INTO doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: You don't need a JOIN. When the user clicks on a vendor, do a query in the Quotations table to get that vendor's quotes.

Comment: You can't insert into both tables at once. You need to do separate inserts for each table.

Comment: I guess you need a `vendor_id` column in quotations table (maybe a partner as well).

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot, it helped me and my issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an table that make the relationship 'Vendor ID' and 'Quotation No'.

In your query, you want to see vendors without quotations? If this the case, the LEFT JOIN you work (beginning the statement with the vendor table). If not, you can use an INNER JOIN. Anyway, you have to include all this 3 tables in the query.

For the inserts, executing them in each table will work.